# Haskell: Resume monadic computation inside IO

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm trying to "resume" a monadic computation from within IO and fearing that I may be out of luck. The situation is the following:

```
ioBracketFoo :: (a - > IO b) -> IO b

withBar :: MonadIO m => (a -> m b) -> m b
withBar action = liftIO $ ioBracketFoo $ \foo -> runMagic (action f)
```

Basically I want to resume my (unknown) monadic computation from within ioBracketFoo. If it were not a bracketing function then I'd be able to get the resource using `res <- liftIO getFoo` and release it later, and I wouldn't have to resume my monadic computation from within IO.

Is there any other creative use of `lift` or similar to make this possible?

Comment: have a look at [MonadBaseControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl). See this tutorial on [fp-complete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/jwiegley/monad-control)

Comment: did you see [bracket](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.0/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:bracket) from lifted-base?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, MonadBaseControl is indeed what i'm looking for. The tutorial is also just what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is sloved by [MonadBaseControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl). `MonadBaseControl` provides the functions to store and restart a monadic computation. You'll require an additional dependency to `MonadBaseControl`, which will prevent unstorable monads from beeing used in your bracket-funciton, for example

There is a tutorial on [fp-complete](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/jwiegley/monad-control), that should answer all basic questions.